# Error in gradle while adding firebase ads dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After I have added the firebase ads dependency implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
now I am getting the followiing Error:

```html
Error:The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,16.0.0), [16.0.0,16.0.0], [16.0.0,99999]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

but I haven't added a analytics dependency since I don't need that, but I added it anyway to see weather it solves the problem but I am still getting the same error
the following is my build.gradle(module app)

```html
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rimapps.midippu"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'` and `implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'` and use only those firebase dependency which you need.

Comment: now I am getting something like this  Error:The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.1.0,16.0.0), [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: can you provide your project level gradle?

Comment: @RohitMaurya It worked after I updated my classpath dependency to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' in my project gradle..thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I updated my classpath dependency to  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' in my project gradle